# Cannot find ./bin scripts when running Nextflow with a container

Tags: nextflow

I have a nextflow script that sources scripts located in the ./bin directory that is located where I invoke the nextflow script. When I run the workflow without a container, Nextflow can find these scripts and execute them. However, when I run Nextflow with a container the scripts cannot be found, despite that I attempted to add those scripts to the container file.

I guess that I am either not adding the executables to the container properly or that I am not referencing them properly in the Nextflow script or config file. Any help is appreciated.

Here is an example process:

```
process clean {
  // Remove common contaminants from fastq(s) using tapioca script
  // see: https://github.com/ncgr/tapioca

  input:
    path fastq_file from fastq_raw
    val x from machine_name

  output:
      path 'out.fastq' into clean_out
      stdout ch1                        

  script:
  """
  echo "Number of reads in $fastq_file"
  grep -c "^@" $fastq_file

  tap_contam_analysis --db ${dbdir}/phix174 --pct 80 ${fastq_file} > hits.txt
  echo "PhiX filtering completed for ${fastq_file}"
  """
}
```

Note that the "tap_contam_analysis" script is a perl script located in ./bin from where I invoke the Nextflow script.

Here are the relevant parts of my Docker file. Note that I attempted to modify the $PATH in hopes that would fix the issue...no luck:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

WORKDIR /usr/src

#Copy all the stuff for this Nextflow workflow (python and perl scripts)
COPY . .
ENV PATH=${PATH}:/usr/src/bin
```

Finally, here is my nextflow.config file:

```
process {    
    container = 'nf_se_demux_to_bam_bai_denovo'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The executables just need to be added to somewhere in your container's `$PATH`. Folks often like to use `/usr/local/bin` for this, but you can check other locations with:

```
docker run --rm ubuntu:18.04 bash -c 'echo $PATH'
```

Your Dockerfile, therefore, might look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY ./bin /usr/local/bin
```